# Задача про свиней

Tags: логика, prolog

Есть задача:

> есть четыре свиньи (а, б, в, г)
>
> они из (австралии, германии, франции, ирландии)
>
> корм (трава, овощи, айца, каштаны)
>
> свинья "б" из германии. австралийская свинья ест овощи. ирландсткая не
>   любит яйца. свинья "в" ест каштаны, а свинья "a" не из франции и ест
>   траву.
>
> Откуда какая свинья и что она ест?

Помогите с решением, что-то я туплю.

Comment: у вас явно ошибка в условии - 'свинья "а" из германии' и 'свинья "а" не из франции'.

Comment: да, действительно, опечатался

Comment: @KoVadim да, действительно, опечатался

Comment: *Помогите с решением, что-то я туплю.* — так покажите, что именно у вас получилось, что не работает.

Comment: Этот вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, почему не имеет? :-)

Comment: вопрос не о программировании.

Answer (score 10):

Подход как решать подобные логические задачи с помощью пролога:

Для начала нужно определить факты, которые известны:

```
имя(а).
имя(б).
имя(в).
имя(г).

корм(трава).
корм(овощи).
корм(яйца).
корм(каштаны).

страна(австралия).
страна(германия).
страна(франция).
страна(ирландия).
```

Далее функция, которая будет решать:

```
solve(Свиньи):-
```

Собираем нужный список, который потом вернем

```
Свиньи = [свинья(А, АСтрана, АКорм), 
          свинья(Б, БСтрана, БКорм), 
          свинья(В, ВСтрана, ВКорм),
          свинья(Г, ГСтрана, ГКорм)],
```

Указываем, что специфицированные значения должны быть уникальны

```
имя(А), имя(Б), имя(В),имя(Г), unique([А,Б,В,Г]),
корм(АКорм), корм(БКорм),корм(ВКорм),корм(ГКорм), unique([АКорм, БКорм, ВКорм,ГКорм]),
страна(АСтрана), страна(БСтрана),страна(ВСтрана),страна(ГСтрана), unique([АСтрана, БСтрана, ВСтрана,ГСтрана]),
```

Далее указываем конкретные условия из задачи

```
% свинья "б" из германии. 
member(свинья(б, германия, _), Свиньи),

% австралийская свинья ест овощи. 
member(свинья(_, австралия, овощи), Свиньи), 

% свинья "в" ест каштаны,
member(свинья(в, _, каштаны), Свиньи), 

% а свинья "a" не из франции и ест траву.
member(свинья(а,НеЛюбитФранцию, трава), Свиньи), not(НеЛюбитФранцию=франция),

% ирландская не любит яйца. 
member(свинья(_, ирландия, НеЛюбитЯйца), Свиньи), not(НеЛюбитЯйца=яйца).
```

Добавляем запускающую функцию, которая вызовет решательную

```
start(Solve):-
  solve(Solve), Solve = [свинья(а, _, _), свинья(б, _, _), свинья(в, _, _), свинья(г,_,_)].
```

При запуске `start(Решение).` получим ответ:

> Решение = [свинья(а, ирландия, трава), свинья(б, германия, яйца), свинья(в, франция, каштаны), свинья(г, австралия, овощи)]
>   false