# Ошибка - Singleton variables

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Есть логическая задача:

Три дочери писательницы Дорис Кей — Джуди, Айрис и Линда, тоже очень талантливы. Они приобрели известность в разных видах искусств — пении, балете и кино. Все они живут в разных городах, поэтому Дорис часто звонит им в Париж, Рим и Чикаго. 
Известно, что:

1. Джуди живет не в Париже, а Линда — не в Риме;
2. парижанка не снимается в кино;
3. та, кто живет в Риме, певица;
4. Линда равнодушна к балету.
   Где живет Айрис, и какова ее профессия?

Мой код выдает ошибку(Singleton variables):

```
name(dzhudi). name(paris). name(linda).
sity(paris). sity(rim). sity(chikago).
talant(penie). talant(balet). talant(kino).

loot(X,Y,Z) :-
    name(X), sity(Y), talant(Z),
    X = dzgudi, not(Y = paris),
    X = linda , not(Y = rim).

loot(X,Y,Z) :-
    name(X), sity(Y), talant(Z),
    Y = paris , not(Z = kino).

loot(X,Y,Z) :-
    name(X), sity(Y), talant(Z),
    Y = rim, Z = penie.

loot(X,Y,Z) :-
    name(X), sity(Y), talant(Z),
    X = linda, not(Z = balet).

result(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3) :-
    X1=dzgudi,loot(X1,Y1,Z1),
    X2=airis,loot(X2,Y2,Z2),
    X3=linda,loot(X3,Y3,Z3),
    Y1 \== Y2, Y2 \== Y3, Y1 \== Y3,
    Z1 \== Z2, Z2 \== Z3, Z1 \== Z3.

result(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3).
```

Помогите исправить плиз)

Comment: на какие именно переменные идет ошибка? Код приведенный в вопросе такой ошибки не дают

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Задача про свиней](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533048/186999)

Answer (score 0):

`Singleton variables` - это не ошибка, а предупреждение, которое сообщает вам, что существуют именованные переменные, которые нигде в дальнейшем не используются. В данном случае, это переменные в предложении

```
result(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3).
```

Это предложение не имеет смысла и больше похоже на цель. Соответственно, чтобы избавится от предупреждения достаточно просто его удалить.

Предложение

```
loot(X,Y,Z) :-
   name(X), sity(Y), talant(Z),
   X = dzgudi, not(Y = paris),
   X = linda , not(Y = rim).
```

всегда вернет `false`, потому что переменная `X` не может быть одновременно согласована со значениями `dzgudi` и `linda`. Поэтому можно разделить его на два предложения или поставить `;`

```
loot(X,Y,Z) :-
   name(X), sity(Y), talant(Z),
   X = dzgudi, not(Y = paris);
   X = linda , not(Y = rim).
```

Кроме того у вас имя Джуди в факте `name` задано как `dzhudi`, а в остальных случаях как `dzgudi`. Есть факт `name(paris)`, хотя `paris` не является именем, но нет факта `name(airis)`.

Если все это исправить, то помимо верного ответа, через перебор с возвратом будут возвращены еще 11 вариантов, не являющихся верными. Это можно исправить с помощью оператора отсечения:

```
result(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3) :-
   X1 = dzhudi, loot(X1,Y1,Z1),
   X2 = airis, loot(X2,Y2,Z2),
   X3 = linda, loot(X3,Y3,Z3),
   Y1 \== Y2, Y2 \== Y3, Y1 \== Y3,
   Z1 \== Z2, Z2 \== Z3, Z1 \== Z3, !.
```

---

Вообще подобные задачи чаще решаются с использованием списков:

```
ayris(City, Prof):-
   dauthers(Dauthers),
   not(member([judi, _, paris], Dauthers)),
   not(member([linda, _, rome], Dauthers)),
   not(member([_, cinema, paris], Dauthers)),
   member([_, singing, rome], Dauthers),
   not(member([linda, balley, _], Dauthers)),
   member([ayris, Prof, City], Dauthers), !.
```

где предикат `dauthers(Dauthers)` возвращает список, состоящий из трех возможных комбинаций `[Имя, Профессия, Город]`, где не повторяются названия городов, имена и профессии.